# Using sed in bash to write to a line number specified by a variable

Tags: linux, bash, sed

My script reads an input file eg. `myscript < testfile` and copies any lines that only have one word on them to a new file.

However, I am trying to write to a certain line number that increases through a loop and also the text variable changes however the sed code I have so far does not give any output to the new file.

```
#!/bin/bash

line_num=1
line_count=0
word_count=0
text_in_line=""

while read line;do
text_in_line="$line"
echo "line $line_num: $(echo $text_in_line | wc -w)"
word_count=$(echo $text_in_line | wc -w)

if [ $word_count = 1 ]; then
    echo "word count is: $word_count"
    ((line_count++))
sed -i "${line_count}i${text_in_line}" newfile.txt

fi
((line_num++))

done
```

Can someone please advise on the correct code. It gives no error however when I open the newfile.txt nothing has been written to it.

Thanks.

Comment: can you provide a  [mcve]?

Comment: Like `cat -n oldfile.txt > newfile.txt`?

Comment: ok i added the whole script.

Comment: I also mean some sample input together with the desired output.

Comment: `sed -i` option is for inplace substitutions on existing files - not new files

Comment: well according to this http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/75803/writing-starting-from-a-certain-line-number-in-a-text-file
that is where I got my idea from for the sed command.

Comment: where is the source text supposed to come from your not connecting `read` to anyting. Are you intending to type text into `read` and use that in your program?

Comment: exactly if you read the question from the post you linked to: *but this file has already been used before and there are texts in it. So I want to echo some additional text in it*

Comment: sorry when i run the script I use 

myscript < testfile

Comment: If you are writing to a new file, you don't have to worry about where you are writing it. Just redirect your output to the file and it will be added sequentially. So if you say `echo 23 >> file` and then `echo 44 >> file`, every time you will get this output into a different line.

Comment: Why create `text_in_line` (you have `line`) and why call `$(echo $text_in_line | wc -w)` twice (spawning multiple subshells each time). Call it once and save the results as `word_count=$(echo $text_in_line | wc -w)` *before* your `echo` statement. The logic and naming seems to make the code a lot more difficult than it is.

Comment: Yeah it works if I already have a file with something in it, just won't work with a blank or non existing file.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 things that are causing your script not to work

**1 you are not reading in from the input file**

your `while / read` statement should be of the form

```
while read line;do
    ...
done < testfile
```

**2 you are incrementing `$line_num` but using `$line_count`**
**3 your `sed` statement is referencing line numbers that don't exist**

I believe this script does what you want - with the limitation that your `testfile` has less lines than new lines in the `printf` statement
(I can't think of a better way to create a  new file with a bunch of lines)

```
#!/bin/bash

line_num=1
line_count=0
word_count=0

printf "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n" > newfile.txt
while read line;do
    text_in_line="$line"
    # echo "line $line_num: $(echo $text_in_line | wc -w)"
    word_count=$(echo $text_in_line | wc -w)
    echo "line count of subject is: $line_count"
    if [ $word_count = 1 ]; then
        echo "word count is: $word_count"
        sed -i "${line_count}i${text_in_line}" newfile.txt
    fi
    (( line_count++ ))
done < testfile
```

Comment: Thankyou. There is no need for the "\n" though as just one is all that is required once the file is made the sed then writes to it and always leaves a blank line at the end of it.

Answer (score 0):

Keep one word lines the rest becomes empty.

```
$ sed -e '/^[[:graph:]]\+$/! s/.*//' <<EOF
word
word word
0123456789
0123456789 0123456789
xxx
xx xx xx
xx xx xx
yyyyyyyy
EOF
```

```
word

0123456789

xxx


yyyyyyyy
```